# Yii Custom Form Field Id Ajax Validation CActiveForm

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm making a system that stores Yii Forms in a database.

I'm having troubles getting one thing to work.

I have several Forms on the same page which are all called DynamicFormModel. To achieve validation on each field I had to use the 'id' and 'inputID' HtmlOptions on my fields and error message dom elements.

```
$domId = 'form_' . $dynamicFormModel->formModel->id . 'language_' . $dynamicFormModel->language->id . 'field_' . $formField->id;
echo $form->textArea($dynamicFormModel, $formField->label, array('id' => $domId));
echo $form->error($dynamicFormModel, $formField->label, array('inputID' => $domId));
```

Client side validation works fine. The problem I'm having is with Ajax Validation. The client side validation now makes the needed events relative to the needed field ID.

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('#AppVersionDetailsForm').yiiactiveform({'attributes':[{'id':'AppVersionDetailsForm_defaultLanguage','inputID':'AppVersionDetailsForm_defaultLanguage','errorID':'AppVersionDetailsForm_defaultLanguage_em_','model':'AppVersionDetailsForm','name':'AppVersionDetailsForm[defaultLanguage]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group','summary':true},{'id':'AppVersionDetailsForm_selectedLanguages','inputID':'AppVersionDetailsForm_selectedLanguages','errorID':'AppVersionDetailsForm_selectedLanguages_em_','model':'AppVersionDetailsForm','name':'AppVersionDetailsForm[selectedLanguages]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}],'summaryID':'AppVersionDetailsForm_es_','errorCss':'error'});
jQuery('#form_1language_1').yiiactiveform({'validateOnType':true,'validateOnChange':true,'attributes':[{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Test','inputID':'form_1language_1field_1','errorID':'form_1language_1field_1_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Test]','enableAjaxValidation':false,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Radio','inputID':'form_1language_1field_2','errorID':'form_1language_1field_2_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Radio]','enableAjaxValidation':false,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}],'errorCss':'error'});
jQuery('#form_2language_1').yiiactiveform({'validateOnType':true,'validateOnChange':true,'validationUrl':'/index.php/appVersion/submitDynamicForm','attributes':[{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Test','inputID':'form_2language_1field_3','errorID':'form_2language_1field_3_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Test]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_test_radio','inputID':'form_2language_1field_4','errorID':'form_2language_1field_4_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[test radio]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Dropdown','inputID':'form_2language_1field_5','errorID':'form_2language_1field_5_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Dropdown]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Check_this','inputID':'form_2language_1field_6','errorID':'form_2language_1field_6_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Check this]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Upload_a_file','inputID':'form_2language_1field_7','errorID':'form_2language_1field_7_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Upload a file]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Upload_an_image','inputID':'form_2language_1field_8','errorID':'form_2language_1field_8_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Upload an image]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}],'errorCss':'error'});
jQuery('#form_2language_3').yiiactiveform({'validateOnType':true,'validateOnChange':true,'validationUrl':'/index.php/appVersion/submitDynamicForm','attributes':[{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Test','inputID':'form_2language_3field_3','errorID':'form_2language_3field_3_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Test]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_test_radio','inputID':'form_2language_3field_4','errorID':'form_2language_3field_4_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[test radio]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Dropdown','inputID':'form_2language_3field_5','errorID':'form_2language_3field_5_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Dropdown]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Check_this','inputID':'form_2language_3field_6','errorID':'form_2language_3field_6_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Check this]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Upload_a_file','inputID':'form_2language_3field_7','errorID':'form_2language_3field_7_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Upload a file]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Upload_an_image','inputID':'form_2language_3field_8','errorID':'form_2language_3field_8_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Upload an image]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}],'errorCss':'error'});
jQuery('#form_2language_4').yiiactiveform({'validateOnType':true,'validateOnChange':true,'validationUrl':'/index.php/appVersion/submitDynamicForm','attributes':[{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Test','inputID':'form_2language_4field_3','errorID':'form_2language_4field_3_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Test]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_test_radio','inputID':'form_2language_4field_4','errorID':'form_2language_4field_4_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[test radio]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Dropdown','inputID':'form_2language_4field_5','errorID':'form_2language_4field_5_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Dropdown]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Check_this','inputID':'form_2language_4field_6','errorID':'form_2language_4field_6_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Check this]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Upload_a_file','inputID':'form_2language_4field_7','errorID':'form_2language_4field_7_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Upload a file]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Upload_an_image','inputID':'form_2language_4field_8','errorID':'form_2language_4field_8_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Upload an image]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}],'errorCss':'error'});
jQuery('#form_2language_6').yiiactiveform({'validateOnType':true,'validateOnChange':true,'validationUrl':'/index.php/appVersion/submitDynamicForm','attributes':[{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Test','inputID':'form_2language_6field_3','errorID':'form_2language_6field_3_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Test]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_test_radio','inputID':'form_2language_6field_4','errorID':'form_2language_6field_4_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[test radio]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Dropdown','inputID':'form_2language_6field_5','errorID':'form_2language_6field_5_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Dropdown]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Check_this','inputID':'form_2language_6field_6','errorID':'form_2language_6field_6_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Check this]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Upload_a_file','inputID':'form_2language_6field_7','errorID':'form_2language_6field_7_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Upload a file]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'DynamicFormModel_Upload_an_image','inputID':'form_2language_6field_8','errorID':'form_2language_6field_8_em_','model':'DynamicFormModel','name':'DynamicFormModel[Upload an image]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}],'errorCss':'error'});
jQuery('body').tooltip({'selector':'a[rel=tooltip]'});
jQuery('body').popover({'selector':'a[rel=popover]'});
jQuery('#yii_bootstrap_collapse_0').collapse({'parent':false,'toggle':false});
});
/*]]>*/
```

The Ajax Validation does not return with the ID of the field but the attribute name. This is the response I'm getting:

```
{"DynamicFormModel_test":["Test cannot be blank."],"DynamicFormModel_radio":["Radio cannot be blank."],"DynamicFormModel_Check":["Check cannot be blank."],"DynamicFormModel_this":["This cannot be blank."],"DynamicFormModel_Upload":["Upload cannot be blank.","Upload cannot be blank."],"DynamicFormModel_a":["A cannot be blank."],"DynamicFormModel_file":["File cannot be blank."],"DynamicFormModel_an":["An cannot be blank."],"DynamicFormModel_image":["Image cannot be blank."]}
```

The binding that is trying to be made will not work. The reason is that I get:

```
"DynamicFormModel_test":["Test cannot be blank."]
```

Whereas I need it to bind to for example: `form_2language_6field_4_em_`

Suggestions please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause was due to a bug. See bugfix https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/3144